# How to write Fibonacci in one line?

Tags: java

I would like to know how can I write a program that give me as output the Fibonacci sequence (until N member) in one line?
The real obligation of my problem is do this program in one line. I know how can I do it with recursion but in only one line, I haven't any idea how can I do that.

Comment: You know, that you don't have to use any line breaks in a Java program?

Comment: Yes, I know that. But the problem is do that with math or something like an operator that I don't know.

Comment: If this is an assignment, can you show us what you've got so far? Your recursion-based program?

Comment: I believe the question is kind of good since you can do a lot in one line with lambda expression in Java 8. anybody agree?

Comment: @KickButtowski A "line" is a useless measure in Java.

Comment: I think OP meant to apply the function is one line but I know any program has to follow the rules

Comment: @KickButtowski - The OP should show at least minimal effort. *I've tried this* would have been sufficient.

Comment: @TheLostMind I totally agree with your thought

Comment: @KickButtowski While code golf can be interesting, that doesn't make this a good question for the site.

Comment: @resueman could you explain what code golf means here?

Comment: @KickButtowski trying to solve a problem with as short of a program as possible.

Comment: @resueman do not u think Lambda expression does that? or I am mistaken?

Comment: You can try using formula described for example here http://sites.cdnis.edu.hk/students/032743/2011/04/02/fibonacci-series/ but you most probably will get incorrect results for bigger numbers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I expect you are looking for the [*ternary operator*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), which lets you compress conditional statements down into a single expression like so:

```
// returns the nth number in the fibonacci sequence
public static int fib(int n) { 
    return (n < 2) ? n : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

### P.S.

This should work for both standard seed conditions of

> F<sub>1</sub> = 1
>   F<sub>2</sub> = 1

or

> F<sub>0</sub> = 0
>   F<sub>1</sub> = 1

See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) for a complete discussion of the math.

Comment: You still need the loop until N

Comment: thanks for your solution azurefrog, but how can add this condition: last number of sequence must be 500 millions?

Comment: @laune Try running it.  It works fine for n >= 0.  Recursive methods don't need to loop.

Comment: @user1743308 The recursive algorithm is pathetically to run, and its memory scaling is horrible, but it's probably the most compact to write down in code.  Something like the fast doubling algorithm would give you large values very quickly, but you aren't going to implement it in one statement. [See here](http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms) for some better algorithms.

Comment: @azurefrog OP: "program [...] as output **the Fibonacci sequence** (until N member)". Where is the loop for the output of the sequence?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this might be considered cheating, but it works :

```
Fib(n) = (Math.pow(Phi,n) – Math.pow(–phi,n)) / Math.sqrt(5);
```

Where Phi = (1 + sqrt(5)) / 2

Or in other words :

```
public static int fib(int n) { 
    return (int)((Math.pow((1+Math.sqrt (5))/2,n)-Math.pow((1-Math.sqrt (5))/2,n))/Math.sqrt (5));
}
```

It's quite accurate.

Test :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{  
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
    System.out.println (fib(i));
}
```

Output :

```
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
21
34
55
89
144
233
377
610
987
1597
2584
4181
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibFormula.html).

Comment: How can mathematcis ever be cheating? Quickly remove this word or I'll -1 you! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a one-line JavaScript version of the iterative approach.

```
function fib(n){var f=[1,1],g=1,h=1,i,t;for(i=2;i<n;i++){t=g+h;g=h;h=t;f.push(t);}return f;}
```

Comment: I think that it isn't the goal. I must need to use only one line, I think that only one operation.